# Create select within select in expression tree

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

How can I create the following with an expression tree?
Assume `claims` is an `IQueryable` of `ClaimData`

```
var lastNames = claims.Select(p1 => p1.Advisors.Select(p2 => p2.LastName));
```

With the example classes as follows:

```
public class ClaimData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<AdvisorData> Advisors { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<ActionData> Actions { get; set; }
}

public class AdvisorData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ActionData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming we don't know which property of ClaimData (Advisors in this example) or which property of that (LastName in this example) we want to Select.

I would like to create the selector but am having difficulty. Here is code that I have attempted, but is incomplete and I am clearly getting confused

```
var property = typeof(ClaimData).GetProperties().Where(p =>
{
    var args = p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
    if (args.Count() == 0) return false;
    var innerProperty = args.First().GetProperties().Where(pi => PropertyByAttributeFunc(pi, table, column));
    return innerProperty.Count() > 0;
}).First();

var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ClaimData), "p1");
var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, property.Name);

var propertyType = property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First();
var parameterInnerExp = Expression.Parameter(propertyType, "p2");
var propertyInner = propertyType.GetProperties().Where(pi => PropertyByAttributeFunc(pi, table, column)).First();
var propertyInnerExp = Expression.Property(parameterInnerExp, propertyInner.Name);

var selectMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "Select").First()
.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType, typeof(string));

var genericFunc = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType, typeof(string));
var genericInnerFunc = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(propertyType, typeof(string));

var innerLambda = Expression.Lambda(genericInnerFunc, propertyInnerExp, parameterInnerExp);

var expCall = Expression.Call(selectMethod, propertyExp, innerLambda);
```

Don't worry about this line:

```
var propertyInner = propertyType.GetProperties().Where(pi => PropertyByAttributeFunc(pi, table, column)).First();
```

It just returns the correct property for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was on the following line:

```
var selectMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Select").First()
    .MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType, typeof(string));
```

`property.PropertyType` is `IQueryable<AdvisorData>`.  What it should be is just `AdvisorData`.  The first generic argument of `Select` is looking for the type of *one item* in the query, rather than the type of the entire `IQueryable`.  This means your `Select` call needs to pass in an `IQueryable<IQueryable<AdvisorData>>` to match the parameter `Select` expects.

The change is simple enough:

```
var selectMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Select").First()
    .MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0], 
        typeof(string));
```